# Angularjs Service does not work

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc

I define a `Service` to share a variable between two controllers, but when i set the variable in a controller and then get this from another controller it does not get the correct value , this is the service:

```
 App.service("ProductService", function () {
    var productTotalCount = {};
    return {
        getproductTotalCount: function () {
            return productTotalCount;
        },

        setproductTotalCount: function (value) {
            productTotalCount = value;
        }
    }
});
```

and this is the controller which i set `productTotalCount`:

```
 App.controller("ProductController", function ($scope, $http, $rootScope, ProductService) {
    $scope.GetAllProducts = $http.get("GetAllProductsInformation").success(function (data) {

        $rootScope.Products = data.Data;
        ProductService.setproductTotalCount(data.TotalCount); // i set productTotalCount here and it's value became 19
    });
    $scope.editProduct = function (data) {

        $scope.model = data;
        $rootScope.$broadcast('modalFire', data)
    }
});
```

and when i get the `productTotalCount` in this controller it return object instead of 19 :

```
 App.controller('Pagination', function ($scope, ProductService) {
    debugger;
    $scope.totalItems = ProductService.getproductTotalCount(); // it should return 19 but return object!!
    $scope.currentPage = 1;
    $scope.itemPerPage = 8;
});
```

what is the problem?
EDIT: this is the html, it may help :

```
<div ng-controller="ProductController" ng-init="GetAllProducts()">

<div class="row" style="margin-top:90px" ng-show="!ShowGrid">
    <article class="widget">
        <header class="widget__header">

            <div class="widget__title">
                <i class="pe-7s-menu"></i><h3>ProductList</h3>
            </div>
            <div class="widget__config">
                <a href="#"><i class="pe-7f-refresh"></i></a>
                <a href="#"><i class="pe-7s-close"></i></a>
            </div>
        </header>

        <div class="widget__content table-responsive">

            <table class="table table-striped media-table">
                <thead style="background-color:rgba(33, 25, 36,0.1)">
                    <tr>
                        <th style="width:40%">edit</th>
                        <th style="width:30%">Price</th>
                        <th style="width:30%">ProductName</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <tr ng-repeat="product in Products">
                        @*<td>{{product.ProductDescription}}</td>*@
                        <td>
                            <input class="btn btn-default" style="padding: 14px;background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2)" type="submit" value="Edit" ng-click="editProduct(product)" />
                        </td>
                        <td>{{product.Price}}</td>
                        <td>{{product.ProductName}}</td>

                    </tr>
                </tbody>
              </table>
           </div>
         </article>
      </div>
    </div>

<div ng-controller="Pagination">
    <pagination total-items="totalItems" ng-change="pageChanged()" previous-text="Before" next-text="Next" first-text="First"
            last-text="Last" ng-model="currentPage" items-per-page="itemPerPage" max-size="maxSize" class="pagination-sm" boundary-links="true"></pagination>

</div>
```

Comment: are you sure its `data.TotalCount` not `data.Data.TotalCount` ?

Comment: yes, because it's a class with two Propertise Data and TotalCount

Comment: check by adding console.log(ProductService.getproductTotalCount()) after you set Total count. I just have doubt that its not set correctly. If created fiddle/plunker then its easy to help.

Comment: attention that the value of productTotalCount  in the "ProductController" was set 19,  when i get it again it return nothing!!

Comment: I do it and return 19!!!

Comment: have you tried adding GetAllProducts to your ProductsService then both controllers will see the same data from the service

Answer (score 1):

From the controller names, I bet the `Pagination` and `ProductController` controllers are both instantiated more or less at the same time, BEFORE invoking the `.setproductTotalCount()` method. If that is the case, then because you are treating the `productTotalCount` variable as a primitive type (instead of an object) after setting it, the changes do not get reflected between the controllers.

Try the following:

```
// Change the service to:
App.service("ProductService", function () {
    var productTotalCount = {};

    return {
        getproductTotalCount: function () {
            return productTotalCount;
        },

        setproductTotalCount: function (value) {
            productTotalCount.value = value;
        }
    }
});

// In Pagination controller:
App.controller('Pagination', function ($scope, ProductService) {
    debugger;
    $scope.totalItems = ProductService.getproductTotalCount(); // this will still be an empty object initially, but when the value is updated in the service, the $scope.totalItems will also be updated
    $scope.currentPage = 1;
    $scope.itemPerPage = 8;

    // this should confirm that changes are being propagated.
    $scope.$watch('totalItems', function(newVal) {
        console.log('totalItems updated. New Value:', newVal);
    });

    // NOTE: Keep in mind that the real productTotalCount will be stored as $scope.totalItems.value;
});
```

---- EDIT ----

Per your comment below, it proves that the solution above DOES work. To prove it, change:

```
    $scope.$watch('totalItems', function(newVal) {
        console.log('totalItems updated. New Value:', newVal);
    });
```

to

```
    $scope.$watch('totalItems', function(newVal) {
        console.log('totalItems updated. New Value:', newVal);
        console.log($scope.totalItems);
    });
```

At that point, you should see that $scope.totalItems has been updated to:

```
{ value: 19 };
```

Comment: I do as u said it does not work, but interesting thing was in  $scope.$watch('totalItems', function(newVal) , that in console return value, but in $scope.totalItems = ProductService.getproductTotalCount(); it returns object!!

Comment: Yes, that proves what I said. The problem is that you are making the assignment: $scope.totalItems = ProductService.getproductTotalCount(); BEFORE you the products controller executes ProductService.setproductTotalCount(data.TotalCount);

Comment: Yes, u right my friend, how can fix it? How can i force the assignment before getting the variable?

Comment: The proposed solution above is the fix. I can't help beyond this point unless I know what you are wanting to do in the Pagination controller. All you posted is the assignment of scope variables totalItems, currentPage and itemPerPage, but I have no clue what you intend to do with them.

Comment: i just need to execute "ProductController" BEFORE "Pagination", is there any way?

Comment: You didn't post any code that indicates how you are binding the controllers to the views (via ng-controller or via state/route configuration, ...) or how the views are related (siblings, parent/child), so it's difficult to say. If you use the solution above though, it doesn't matter. Please explain what still doesn't work for you after implementing the suggested solution.

Comment: Its really difficult to bring more code here, any way thanks for ur help, u give the clue

Answer (score 0):

The issue may be how you're declaring your variable in your service.  Because it's a local variable in the function rather than returned object, I believe it will be creating a new variable for each time you inject the service as a dependency.  Try making the variable a member of the returned object. E.g.

```
App.service("ProductService", function () {
  return {
    productTotalCount: 0, 
    getproductTotalCount: function () {
      return this.productTotalCount;
    },

    setproductTotalCount: function (value) {
      this.productTotalCount = value;
    }
  }
});
```